# Gerrit HEAD:refs/publish/master blocks change

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

When trying to upload my changes to gerrit with `git review` I am getting this error message:

```
Fetching gerrit
2018-01-26 13:33:52.161429 Running: git rev-parse HEAD
2018-01-26 13:33:52.166465 Running: git show-ref --quiet --verify refs/remotes/gerrit/master
2018-01-26 13:33:52.172314 Running: git rebase -p -i remotes/gerrit/master
2018-01-26 13:33:53.075322 Running: git reset --hard b8fb53d42c568aaed3216758076b5a5d2df6ebc6
2018-01-26 13:33:53.086334 Running: git config --get-colorbool color.review true
2018-01-26 13:33:53.091360 Running: git log --color=always --decorate --oneline HEAD --not --remotes=gerrit
2018-01-26 13:33:53.098427 Running: git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD
2018-01-26 13:33:53.105430 Running: git log --pretty='%B' HEAD^1..HEAD
Using local branch name "master" for the topic of the change submitted
2018-01-26 13:33:53.113735 Running: git push gerrit HEAD:refs/publish/master
fatal: One or more refs/publish/ names blocks change upload
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My ssh key works; I can ssh clone projects from gerrit without errors; and `git review -s` is working correctly. My git config:

```
remote.origin.url=git@gitlab.test.lt:tt-java/service-client.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
remote.gerrit.url=ssh://test.test@review.test.lt:29418/service-client.git
remote.gerrit.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gerrit/*

gerrit  ssh://test.test@review.test.lt:29418/service-client.git (fetch)
gerrit  ssh://test.test@review.test.lt:29418/service-client.git (push)
origin  git@gitlab.test.lt:tt-java/service-client.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.test.lt:tt-java/service-client.git (push)
```

`git review` was installed via homebrew on osx. I've read about publishing to `refs/for/master`, but gettings same error. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**refs/publish vs refs/for**

`refs/publish/*` is just an alternative name for `refs/for/*` - there's no difference using one of them.

**The issue**

Your server repository has a branch under the `refs/for/` namespace. Gerrit refuses to work when this happens because now `refs/for/` (which normally is a "magical" branch) is actually a real branch in the Git repository.

This branch was probably created, by mistake, for a user pushing directly to the Git repository rather than to the  Gerrit SSH port.

**How to fix**

To see which refs already exist, the Gerrit administrator needs to go to that specific repository and execute:

```
git for-each-ref refs/for
```

He needs to delete all of those refs or rename them to a different name. Normally it's safe to just remove all of them executing the following:

```
for n in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/for); do git
update-ref -d $n; done
```

**More info**

See [here](https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/error-change-upload-blocked.html).

Comment: Correct, thanks. Just in case I had error with refs/publish, I must do fix on refs/publish too, not on refs/for.

Comment: Ok, I thought of this refs/for vs refs/publish point after I had wrote the answer... thanks for your comment.